# How to create a wireless link over great distances?

Tags: wireless-networking

Me and a few friends want to try to create a wifi network that'll connect our houses. We have a "clear line of sight" in a sense that they live lower than me and there are no other hills between us.

Is there a name for this? Are there any articles that can help out on the basics?

Comment: http://www.radiolabs.com/Articles/wifi-antenna.html seems good.

Comment: What's the approximate distance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to set up [long-range Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-range_Wi-Fi), all of which essentially involve a pair of directional antennae. The antennae can simply be wireless router antennae placed near the foci of anything roughly paraboloidal in shape, e.g. a metallic bowl, a can, or a satellite disk.

Depending on distance, standard wireless cards [rigged to a can](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna) may suffice. For long distances, you'll need to position an antenna in a satellite dish with some precision.

Try getting in touch with ham radio enthusiasts. There are several forums that can probably help you; read about [these guys](http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=16548), who set up a 304 km link.

Also see [What are some options for transfering large files without using the Internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/318653/what-are-some-options-for-transfering-large-files-without-using-the-internet/318679#318679).

Answer (score 3):

We've had really good luck with Ubiquiti radios for similar links.  You're looking for a point-to-point PtP wireless link.  You'll definitely want to use directional antennas.  If you've got clear line of site including room for the freznel zones it's fairly simple.  How far apart are your sites?

[This tool](http://www.ubnt.com/airlink/) is based around UBNT gear but it makes it pretty simple to get an idea what you're looking at.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a range of about 10km using [a pair of woks.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WokFi)

Comment: Best idea yet!!